# JavaScript - re-dispatch keyup event on DATE input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking for a way to re-dispatch `keyup` KeyboardEvent coming from one **native date input** element to a another one **in real time** (it's similar to **writing** in two date inputs at the same time).

I tried the code below with **text input**, it worked well.

But using the same logic with date input did not do the job: no thing was written on the second date input despite the reception of dispatched event.

[Reproduced code in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dxs8w4zj/)

Here is my code:
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

  <input id="startDate" type="date" />
  <input id="endDate" type="date" />

  <input id="text1" type="text" />
  <input id="text2" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
let startDate = document.getElementById('startDate'),
    endDate = document.getElementById('endDate'),
    text1 = document.getElementById('text1'),
    text2 = document.getElementById('text2')
;

let endDateBinded = this.dispatchElementEvnt.bind(null,[endDate]),
    text2Binded = this.dispatchElementEvnt.bind(null,[text2]);

startDate.addEventListener('keyup', endDateBinded);
endDate.addEventListener('keyup',selfUpdate);

text1.addEventListener('keyup', text2Binded);
text2.addEventListener('keyup',selfUpdate);

function dispatchElementEvnt(secondElement,e){
    let event = new KeyboardEvent(e.type,e);
    secondElement[0].dispatchEvent(event);
}

function selfUpdate(e) {
    this.value += e.key;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the startDate is invalid (i.e. dd/mm/2021) until it is changed to a valid date (i.e. 12/8/2021) so unfortunately both dates won't change in real time,  however both can be changed after startDate has a valid date.

credit: [Changing two input type dates at the same time](https://martinbosanacjs.blogspot.com/2021/08/changing-multiple-input-type-date.html)

The code  below changes the endDate after the StartDate is set:

```
let startDate = document.getElementById('startDate'),
    endDate = document.getElementById('endDate'),
    text1 = document.getElementById('text1'),
    text2 = document.getElementById('text2')
;

let endDateBinded = this.dispatchElementEvnt2.bind(null,[endDate]),
    text2Binded = this.dispatchElementEvnt.bind(null,[text2]);

startDate.addEventListener('change', endDateBinded);
endDate.addEventListener('keyup',selfUpdate2);

text1.addEventListener('keyup', text2Binded);
text2.addEventListener('keyup',selfUpdate);

function dispatchElementEvnt(secondElement,e){
    let event = new KeyboardEvent(e.type,e);
    secondElement[0].dispatchEvent(event);
}

function selfUpdate(e) {
    this.value += e.key;
    
}
function dispatchElementEvnt2(secondElement,e){
    let event = new KeyboardEvent(e.type,e);
    secondElement[0].dispatchEvent(event);
    endDate.value= startDate.value;
}

function selfUpdate2(e) {
    this.value += e.key;
    
}
```

Comment: Hello @Vedran , first i thank you for your try.. To put you in the context: i exactly did the same suggestion yesterday to make a B plan for my issue too (before your answer).. but i still need a solution for the **real time** or at least a **workaround** for it. I give you +1 for your try.